# Why is my code not reaching the While Loop to register my Voice Assistant Wakeword?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, voice-recognition, pyttsx

I'm creating a Voice Assistant using Python. I'm using pyttsx3 for Text-to-Speech and I have a wakeword set up to activate the Voice Assistant. I'm using the Voice Assistant to do things such as read my calendar and such in a While Loop. But suddenly, the wakeword stops working. What is stopping my code from reaching the While Loop and the rest of the code?

Here is some of the code for my project:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
import pytz
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import time
import os
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path


def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said.lower()


WAKE = "Jarvis"
print("Jarvis is ready")

while True:
    print("Jarvis is listening...")
    text = get_audio()

    if text.count(WAKE) > 0:
        speak("Hello Sir, what would you like?")
        text = get_audio()

        DONE = ["never mind", "goodbye", "I'm done now"]
        for phrase in DONE:
           if phrase in text:
               speak("Alright sir. Goodbye!")
               quit()

        NOTE_STRS = ["make a note", "write this down", "remember this"]
        for phrase in NOTE_STRS:
            if phrase in text:
                speak("Sure. What would you like me to write down?")
                note_text = get_audio()
                note(note_text)
                speak("Done Sir. I've made a note of that.")

        TIME = ["time"]
        for phrase in TIME:
            if phrase in text:
                import datetime
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                speak("The current time is %d hours %d minutes" % (now.hour, now.minute))
```

Please tell me if any code is missing and I can send it to help solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

HyperionBlaze - What is happening with authenticate_google(). Is there any exception on that call?

Comment: That is for the Google Calendar API code that I have not included since I didn't think it would be necessary. I just removed it since it didn't need to be there. Tell if if you think it would help if I add all my code.